# A question about continuous and convex functions

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $ f:[0,1]\rightarrow R $ a continuous function. It is true that, if $ f $ is also convex, than
$$ f\left(\frac{a +b}{2}\right) \leq \frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} f.$$
How to prove this?
It holds a reverse of this statement, i.e. f is convex if
$$ f\left(\frac{a +b}{2}\right) \leq \frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} f   ?$$
Thank you for the help.

Comment: What does "a "viceversa" " mean?

Comment: I would say a sort of reverse of the statement, i.e. f is conves if....

Comment: You need to elaborate what you mean by the reverse. Explicitly, not with ellipses.

Comment: What does ... mean??????

Comment: Are you on $[0,1]$ or $[a,b]?$

Comment: The function is defined on $ [0,1]$

Comment: So then you might want to say for all $a,b\in [0,1].$

Comment: It looks unlikely that the converse holds. Take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026144/is-jensens-inequality-an-iff-condition-on-convex-functions)

Answer (score 1):

Since ${1 \over 2}(a+b) = {1 \over b-a} \int_a^b x dx $, Jensen gives
$f({1 \over 2}(a+b)) \le {1 \over b-a} \int_a^b f(x) dx $.

If you take $f_n$ to be the function defined by the graph (with $m={1 \over 2} (a+b)$):
$(a,1), (m-{1 \over n}, 1), (m,0), (m+{1 \over n},1), (b,1)$ then
it should be clear that $f_n$ is not convex and $f_n(m) = 0$ for all $m$ and $\int f_n >0 $.

Comment: Your function $f_n$ satisfies the inequality for fixed values of $a$ and $b$ while the converse problem assumes it does so for every pair $a<b$. The constant functions, for example, are convex and satisfies the inequality for every pair $a<b$.

Comment: @lzralbu: It was not clear at the time of writing (and still needs to be clarified) that that is what the OP meant.